# Trigger not updating last login from user to account object

Tags: apex, trigger

I created one trigger on the User object which will update the last login to account if the account name matches with `user.Name` field.

but somehow my trigger is not at all updating the `LastLogin` field on account object even though name matches, can anyone help me out in this issue here.

My trigger code is below

```
trigger USERLOGIN on User (after insert, after Update) {
map<string, User> ObjMap = new map<string, User>();

for(User obj: Trigger.new)
{
    if (obj.Name != Null)
    {
        ObjMap.put(obj.Name, obj);
    }
}
system.debug('UserMap :' + ObjMap);
List<Account> accounts = [SELECT Id, logindate__c,Name FROM Account WHERE Name IN :ObjMap.KeySet()];
List<Account> accUpdateList = new List<Account>();
system.debug('Account :' + accounts);

for(Account c: accounts)
{
    User obj = ObjMap.get(c.Name);
    c.logindate__c = obj.LastLoginDate;
    c.usertextemail__c = obj.Email;
    accUpdateList.add(c);
}

if(accUpdateList.size() > 0)
{
    update accUpdateList;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is simple: the User record is not updated when the user logs into the platform. Because of this your trigger will not run.

I issued the following query in my orgs' developer console:

```
SELECT Id, LastLoginDate, LastModifiedDate FROM User WHERE Id = '0054T000000sHrOQAU'
```

And the result is:

```
Id                 LastLoginDate                LastModifiedDate
0054T000000sHrOQAU 2020-01-13T13:08:10.000+0000 2020-01-13T13:09:49.000+0000
```

Note that the dates differ. The login date was updated when I logged in, but the last modified date was updated only after I opened the developer console.

You can query the [EventLogFile](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile.htm) table for the [Login Event Type](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile_login.htm) instead (triggers not supported).

Answer (score 2):

Login events do not trigger User triggers, because it is not a real "edit" to the record. You can use a [Login Flow](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_login_flow_create.htm) to do all kinds of things, such as enforcing 2FA or, in your case, performing an update on a related record when a user logs in. Please read the documentation for more information.

Answer (score -1):

Code looks fine to me. I guess you are doing Unit Testing incorrectly.
The trigger point here is after an insert / update happens on any User Record. Then it would check for User.Name == Account.Name and then updates the Account Record.
 Are there any failures?